# Python API JSON upload file multipart/form-data with boundary

Tags: python, json, api, multipart, form-data

I'm trying to upload *.xlsx file by API using python3 and when i POST i receive this:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-01-08T07:47:44.462+0000",
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
  "message" : "Required request part 'file' is not present",
  "path" : "/importFile/"
}
```

part of code:

```
    base_url_import = "URL/importFile/"
    headers_import = {'accept':'*/*', 'Cookie':downloaded_cookies, 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=------WebKitFormBoundaryTChBFmdSvOIemd9N--'}
    payload_import = {'Content-Disposition':'form-data; name=file; filename=file_to_upload',
                      'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}

    response_import = ses.post(base_url_import, data=json.dumps(payload_import), headers=headers_import)
```

i try to change section
filename=file_to_upload to specific path to the file
but effect is the same

when i change json.dumps to json.loads i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./api_import_file.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "./api_import_file.py", line 42, in main
    response_import = ses.post(base_url_import, data=json.loads(payload_import), headers=headers_import)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing data keyword with json such as

```
response_import = ses.post(base_url_import, json=json.dumps(payload_import), headers=headers_import)
```

Comment: unfortunetly is the same effect:
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-01-08T08:47:55.708+0000",
  "status" : 400,
  "error" : "Bad Request",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
  "message" : "Required request part 'file' is not present",
  "path" : "/globitel/importer/importFile/"
}